# Custom Fields through plugin in a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-field

I'm new to wordpress and would like to know what's the best way of extending my custom plugin for our school page. I've created a custom post type experiment which will always have steps 1 to N. Sometimes an experiment might have 3 steps and sometimes 12 steps.

I've looked at custom fields and from the documentation the key-value storage would require always having the maximum number of fields and then checking if a key's value is empty when iterating through it inside the template.

What I'd like to do is to have ajaxed fields like there are for a normal post.

Comment: Why do they have to be stored individually? Store an array in a single field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that Wordpress works with arrays inside a custom post_meta by default.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/124374)

Comment: @cjbj this _is_ the author. :)

Comment: @rarst didn't see that in the review window ;-)